# Filtering a list, removing all items but "like" items

Tags: python

Im trying to filter the output from a `subprocess.check_output` call. The problem is that the Im not sure how to filter on something that is "like" something.  I am trying to filter on items that are in this format domain\username. The domain is known but the username could be anything.

I have tried using multiple `cut -d"" -f3` type filters but its not accurate, its extremely dirty and Id rather not have to use non native windows commands to remove the need to install ports, there must be a more elegant and efficient way of doing it? Im hoping someone may be able to help me.

Below is the snipper of the code i have so far and what I have attempted

```
def tllocal(domain):
        try:
            out = subprocess.check_output(["tasklist", "/V", "/FI", "USERNAME eq %s\*" % domain]).split('\n')
            tasklist = [task for task in out if task != '']
            if tasklist != None:
                return tasklist
            else:
                pass
        except CalledProcessError as e:
            print(e.returncode)
```

I have made various inelegant attempts, similar to the below

```
def tllocal(domain):
        try:
            #out = subprocess.check_output(["tasklist", "/V", "/FI", "USERNAME eq %s\\*" % domain]).split('\n')
            cmdtask1 = 'tasklist /V /FI "USERNAME eq %s\\*" |cut -d" " -f48'
            cmdtask2 = 'tasklist /V /FI "USERNAME eq %s\\*" |cut -d" " -f49'
            cmdtask3 = 'tasklist /V /FI "USERNAME eq %s\\*" |cut -d" " -f50'
            out1 = subprocess.check_output(cmdtask1).split('\n')
            out2 = subprocess.check_output(cmdtask2).split('\n')
            out3 = subprocess.check_output(cmdtask3).split('\n')
            tasklist1 = [task for task in out1 if task != 'etc']
            tasklist2 = [task for task in out2 if task != 'Running']
            tasklist3 = [task for task in out3 if task != 'etc']
            mergedlist = tasklist1 + tasklist2 + tasklist3
            clean1 = [task for task in mergedlist if task != 'Console']
            print clean1
        except CalledProcessError as e:
            print(e.returncode)
```

Data i am trying to filter is below, im trying to collect just "DOMAIN\USER" in the list.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\xpuser>tasklist /V

Image Name                   PID Session Name     Session#    Mem Usage Status
    User Name                                              CPU Time Window T
itle
========================= ====== ================ ======== ============ ========
======= ================================================== ============ ========
================================================================
System Idle Process            0 Console                 0         16 K Running
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                    25:44:53 N/A

System                         4 Console                 0        212 K Running
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                     0:00:06 N/A

smss.exe                     372 Console                 0        408 K Running
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                     0:00:00 N/A

csrss.exe                    588 Console                 0      3,456 K Running
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                     0:00:03 N/A

winlogon.exe                 612 Console                 0      5,420 K Running
     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                     0:00:36 N/A

services.exe                 656 Console                 0      3,824 K Running
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                     0:00:00 N/A

lsass.exe                    668 Console                 0      1,736 K Running
       NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                     0:00:00 N/A

svchost.exe                  824 Console                 0      5,384 K Running
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                     0:00:00 N/A

svchost.exe                  892 Console                 0      4,628 K Running
    NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE                            0:00:00 N/A

svchost.exe                  984 Console                 0     20,484 K Running
     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                     0:00:04 N/A

svchost.exe                 1032 Console                 0      3,452 K Running
    NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE                            0:00:00 N/A

svchost.exe                 1132 Console                 0      6,812 K Running
    NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE                              0:00:00 N/A

spoolsv.exe                 1408 Console                 0      4,652 K Running
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                     0:00:00 N/A

svchost.exe                 1512 Console                 0      3,696 K Running
    NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE                              0:00:00 N/A

snmp.exe                    1612 Console                 0      3,752 K Running
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                     0:00:00 N/A

alg.exe                      196 Console                 0      3,592 K Running
    NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE                              0:00:00 N/A

explorer.exe                 488 Console                 0     17,004 K Running
    WXP\xpuser                                              0:00:03 N/A

ctfmon.exe                   508 Console                 0      3,776 K Running
    WXP\xpuser                                              0:00:00 N/A

MagicDisc.exe               1068 Console                 0      1,236 K Running
    WXP\xpuser                                              0:00:00 N/A

svchost.exe                 1624 Console                 0      3,416 K Running
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                     0:00:00 N/A

cmd.exe                     1688 Console                 0      2,696 K Running
    WXP\xpuser                                              0:00:00 C:\WINDO
WS\system32\cmd.exe - tasklist /V
mmc.exe                     2512 Console                 0     13,796 K Running
    WXP\xpuser                                              0:00:00 Computer
 Management
tasklist.exe                3624 Console                 0      4,704 K Running
    WXP\xpuser                                              0:00:00 OleMainT
hreadWndName
wmiprvse.exe                2980 Console                 0      5,820 K Running
    NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE                            0:00:00 N/A
C:\Documents and Settings\xpuser>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'like'?

Comment: apologies i wasnt very clear. I mean like because the username is unknown so the filter would be `if item in list is LIKE "DOMAIN\*"` hope that makes sense.

Comment: Please post an example of the output and what you want so those of us not on Windows can help you.

Comment: Do you mean `if r'DOMAIN\' in line:`?

Comment: I have add an example in the question

Comment: @m.wasowski maybe. could you give me an example of how to use it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular task this should give you a list of domain\user strings:

example of input:

```
txt = """System                         4 Console                 0        212 K Running
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                     0:00:06 N/A

smss.exe                     372 Console                 0        408 K Running
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                     0:00:00 N/A"""
```

filter:

```
users = [word for word in txt.split() if '\\' in word]
```

output:

```
In [18]: users
Out[18]: ['AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM', 'AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM']

In [19]: for user in users: print(user)
AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
```

*Edit*: .split() added (removed by mistake)